# Separate Container and Shiro Sessions?

Tags: java, tomcat, shiro

We use Apache Shiro to provide security for 4 applications running within one Tomcat instance. They are deployed as 4 WARs, with all the Shiro config and security in a 5th WAR.

In order to provide SSO across these applications, we've configured ehCache to share sessions between all 5 web apps (the original intention was to use multiple containers, but this never happened).

The problem we are facing is that in sharing the sessions across the apps, we are also sharing all object data placed into the session. This is a problem because the apps have different dependencies and hence different classpaths, leading to ClassNotFoundExceptions. I think I'm right in saying that by default in a Tomcat container each WAR would have a separate session and so this would not be problem, but then we would not be able to share the Shiro user data!

So my question is this: Is it possible to have separate Shiro and Container sessions? This would allow the desired outcome i.e. any login data that Shiro uses would be placed into the 'Shiro' session and shared across the multiple apps, while the Container sessions would be separate for each app and therefore no data would be shared between them.

Answer (score 0):

Shiro needs to run in each container. Then those containers need to share the Shiro session. https://shiro.apache.org/session-management.html#session-storage

You could do this using the container's session sharing capabilities or with Shiro's.

Comment: Thanks Brian, we only have one container and we are using ehCache to share the Shiro session across applications however this is also sharing the servlet sessions as well. This is what we are looking to change.

Comment: The idea is still the same, you could either configure Tomcat's session sharing feature (it's been a while since I've done it, but i'm sure there are a ton of articles) or you can use Shiro's session sharing (from the link above).